# WARNING: Server requests forwarding for unknown listen_port 0

Tags: windows, ssh, reverse-proxy, port-forwarding, ssh-tunnel

I am trying to create reverse ssh tunnel between machine A and B. Both machines are windows and using [Win32 OpenSSH](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/wiki/Install-Win32-OpenSSH). Here is what I do.

- On machine A I have a web app running on port 8080
- On machine B I have sshd working
- On machine A I run this command `ssh -v -R 9000:localhost:8080 user@MachineB`

Then, I see below lines on console  of machine A

```
debug1: Remote connections from LOCALHOST:9000 forwarded to local address localhost:8080
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug1: remote forward success for: listen 9000, connect localhost:8080
debug1: All remote forwarding requests processed
```

When I make call to `localhost:9000` on machine B, I see below errors on the console of machine A.

```
debug1: client_input_channel_open: ctype forwarded-tcpip rchan 3 win 2097152 max 32768
debug1: client_request_forwarded_tcpip: listen localhost port 0, originator :: port 52487
WARNING: Server requests forwarding for unknown listen_port 0
debug1: failure forwarded-tcpip
```

Where am I going wrong? How can I troubleshoot this issue?

UPDATE

Also, when I make call to `localhost:9000` on machine B, below lines are written into `sshd.log` file.

```
6388 10:06:47 708 error: getsockname failed: Bad address
6388 10:06:47 745 channel 3: open failed: administratively prohibited: open failed
```

Answer (score 1):

*When I make call to localhost:9000 on machine B*

Check if it works replacing "localhost" by 127.0.0.1 in this step

If that is the case it means the tunnel is OK but the port is not visible from the outside of your ssh server. Solution: take a look at:

- The sshd_config file of your openssh server has **GatewayPorts yes**
- That the **firewall** in the openssh server is not blocking it